# How to order the data in oracle sql if the data have '<' before numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data with age groupings below-

```
CASE WHEN AGE = '000' THEN '<1'
      WHEN AGE  BETWEEN '001' AND '004' THEN '01-04'
      WHEN AGE  BETWEEN '005' AND '014' THEN '05-14'
      WHEN AGE  BETWEEN '015' AND '024' THEN '15-24'
```

When I run it I want the AGE order to be displayed as - '<1','01-04','05-14','15-24'
But the order is displaying as - '01-04','05-14','15-24','<1'
I have the other columns as well. This is how my order by statement is-
ORDER BY YEAR,TO_DATE(DEATH_MONTH,'MM'),AGE,GENDER ;
Is there any logic I can use to display the way I want rather than mentioning
WHEN AGE between  '000' and '001'THEN '00-01'

Appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Order by age first:

```
ORDER BY AGE, YEAR, TO_DATE(DEATH_MONTH,'MM'), GENDER;
```

Comment: What is the data type of the AGE column?  It _should_ be number, but you are comparing it to a character string.  And instead of DEATH_MONTH, you should be storing the actual date of death, not just the month.  And what do you expect to get from TO_DATE, when all you give it is a month?